# Powers getting freezed, getting blue and not usable in lol wild rift at times

Tags: league-of-legends, league-of-legends-wild-rift

Powers getting freezed, getting blue and not usable in lol wild rift at times. At the time of attacking an opponent my powers kinda freezes and are not usable.. How to solve this issue.. I know its a dumb question., but please bear. Attached image [image]

In this pic the powers are blued out. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many characters in League of Legends use a resource called "Mana" to power their spells. Evelyn, whom you're playing in the picture above, is one such champion.

The abilities show up in blue because you do not have enough mana to activate them. The simplest solution is to return to the fountain, where your character will rapidly recover both health *and* mana.

In terms of longer term strategies to avoid running out, there are plenty of available items in the store that increase mana, mana regeneration, or both, and the Ancient Golem (aka "Blue Buff") will rapidly refill a percentage of your resources as well.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I am so new to lol. I suck at this at times so gotta learn.